# How do I access JSON file after filtering and pushing into array

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

I have a massive problem with my weather app.

I'm using the OpenweatherMap free API and I created a page with two select inputs: one for choosing a country from an array of objects stated directly within the state and second select for choosing a city.

The second select is tricky since I uploaded a huge JSON file containing a list of all cities served by the API and I want to filter out every city which does not belong to the previously chosen country.

My issue is that the `generateCitiesList()` function doesn't pass filtered elements into the `this.state.cityList`

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CITIES from "./cities.json";
import COUNTRIES from "./countries.json";
import "./styles.css";


   // So getCitiesByCountry accepts (country) parameter for which we use 
   // this.state.selectedCountry and filter how exactly?

   // Do we compare every element within cities.json file so that it returns
   // an object (array?) that meets the criteria of element.country being equal to
   // this.state.selectedCountry?

const getCitiesByCountry = (country) =>
  CITIES.filter(city => city.country === country);

// 

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { selectedCoutnry: "" };

  handleOnSelectCountry = e => {
    this.setState({ selectedCoutnry: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {


      // What does this line of code do? It looks like an object destructurization
      // so should I assume that from now on
      // const selectedCountry is equal to this.state.selectedCountry ?

    const { selectedCoutnry } = this.state;


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <select value={selectedCoutnry} onChange={this.handleOnSelectCountry}>
          <option>Select a Country</option>

          // That makes a lot of sense. Why would I store countries list in state 
          while I could access it via JSON file.

          {COUNTRIES.map(({ name, id }) => (
            <option value={id} key={id}>
              {name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        {selectedCoutnry && (
          <select>
            <option>Select a City</option>

            // So we use a function getCitiesByCountry which returns a filtered object 
           //  which is then mapped through to render <option>s?

            {getCitiesByCountry(selectedCoutnry).map(({ name, id }) => (
              <option value={id} key={id}>
                {name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 1283378,
    "name": "Gorkhā",
    "country": "NP",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 84.633331,
      "lat": 28
    }
  }
]

Comment: Is it possible to get a more concise code example, focusing only on the issue itself?

Comment: From my limited understanding of React, state is supposed to be immutable, so you should creating a new array, then calling `setState` to replace the existing `cityList` property with that new array. Right now you're modifying the list directly.

Comment: Okay, here's the issue in short - this.state.listCity on the console.log below shows an empty array;


`generateCitiesList = () => { </br>

        const self = this;
       const filterCities = citiesList.filter(function (countries) {
           return countries.country === `${self.state.country}`;
       });

        const citiesArray = [];
        citiesArray.push(filterCities)
        console.log(citiesArray)

        this.setState ({
            listCity: citiesArray
        });

        console.log(this.state.listCity)

    };

`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I updated the issue in the thread above since code formatting doesnt work in comments. I'm doing exactly as you said but it doesnt work

Comment: @YoavKadosh I just did in the first post above

Comment: You shouldn't need to push the filtered items into a new array. Just set the state with the `filterCities` array. Note also that you can filter using arrow functions: `const filterCities = citiesList.filter((countries) => countries.country === this.state.country);` A bit easier to read (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't work because of this:

```
citiesArray.push(filterCities)
```

which should've been written as:

```
citiesArray.push(...filterCities)
```

But you can avoid all that by reducing your code to:

```
generateCitiesList = () => { 
    this.setState ({
        listCity: citiesList.filter(({country}) => (
            country === `${this.state.country}`;
        ))
    });
};
```

However, you should only use the state for storing **the minimum data that affects the view**, in your case - the selected *country/city*.

The list of cities for the currently selected country **should not be part of the state** since **it can be derived from the selected country**.
Simply write a function that takes a country and return the list of cities for that country, and run it in the `render()` against the selected country:

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <select>
            {getCitiesByCountry(this.state.country).map(city => (
                <option value={city}>{city}</option>
            ))}
        </select>
        ...
    );
}
```

[image: Edit vigorous-cdn-3kk92]

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know I can perform operations other than assigning values within this.setState updater.

From what I undersand I take the "country" key within citiesList JSON object (why the {} though?) and return a new array containing only the filtered elements which is then assigned to this.state.cityList?

Comment: The curly braces are for object destructuring. So `obj.foo` is the same as `const {foo} = obj`

Comment: As for "Simply write a function that takes a country and return the list of cities for that country, " do you mean that instead of storying the countryList in an array within state I should filter both country and city list from the same JSON file and then pass the selected values to the API fetch funciton?

Comment: Assuming that you have a list of all the cities and you want to filter them by country, the `getCitiesByCountry(...)` would do that, based on the given country. The output of the function is an array that can be used to create the list of `<option/>` items for the select input.

Comment: OMG, I lacked invoking function within render x_X. 

     <div className="citySelect col-12 col-sm-6 text-center mt-5 mb-5 ">
                        <label> Select City </label>

                            {this.showCitiesList()}
                            
                    </div>

But it makes no sense - I invoked the function within callback of this.generateCitiesList using ()

Comment: I’ll try to post a fiddle soon

Comment: It works now but how do I synchronize state update? After I choose country for the first time the this.state.cityList returns empty since state didnt manage to update.

After another choice of country state logs previously selected country list. The same goes for city. That way I cannot synchornize neither timing of updates nor countries list with cities list

Comment: If you look at the second part of my answer you’ll see that you don’t really need to keep the cityList in your state, all you need in your state is the selected country, and from that you can derive the list of cities in the render

Comment: Oh, you mean I can map the results directly onto page instead of storing cities result in state and then maping them onto page?

But I don't understand this syntax 

getCitiesByCountry(this.state.country).map(city => (
                <option value={city}>{city}</option> .

How does it work? "getCitiesByCountry" is some sort of new function I don't have yet? "this.state.country" is a parameter within this function upon which I run map through?

Comment: Guys, how about FILTER? I updated the code in post topic above. Why don't I filter the JSON file via the this.state.country and return only the cities which meet this criteria?

The only problem I have now is that the function cannot read this.state.country, perhaps because of it being invoked before this .state.country was selected by the user

Comment: @WojciechWojas I've updated my answer with a live example via CodeSandbox, hope that helps clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

See if that works for you.

This is representing your JSON with the cities.

```
cities: {
  city1: {
    cityName: 'City1',
    country: 'A'
  },
  city2: {
    cityName: 'City2',
    country: 'A'
  },
  city3: {
    cityName: 'City3',
    country: 'B'
  },
  city4: {
    cityName: 'City4',
    country: 'B'
  }
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      selectedCountry: 'A',
      countries: ['A','B'],
      cities: {
       city1: {cityName: 'City1',
       country: 'A'},
       city2: {cityName: 'City2',
       country: 'A'},
       city3: {cityName: 'City3',
       country: 'B'},
       city4: {cityName: 'City4',
       country: 'B'},
      }
    }
    this.selectCountry = this.selectCountry.bind(this);
  }
  
  selectCountry() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return({
        ...prevState,
        selectedCountry: prevState.selectedCountry === 'A' ? 'B' : 'A'
      });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
  
    let filteredCities = [];
    
    for (let i in this.state.cities) {
      this.state.selectedCountry === this.state.cities[i].country ?
        filteredCities.push(this.state.cities[i]) : null;
    }
    
    filteredCities = filteredCities.map((item)=> 
      <li>{item.cityName}</li>
    );
    
    return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Selected Country: {this.state.selectedCountry}</div>
      <button onClick={this.selectCountry}>Change Country</button>
      <div>Country List</div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {filteredCities}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Guys, I don't want to rewrite all the code. This bit up there won't work since Im using json file source and it doesnt update as it should

Comment: is your JSON with the cities an array of objects?

Comment: Yes, it is:


[
  {
    "id": 707860,
    "name": "Hurzuf",
    "country": "UA",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 34.283333,
      "lat": 44.549999
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 519188,
    "name": "Novinki",
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.666668,
      "lat": 55.683334
    }
  },
]

Answer (score 0):

This looks evil. Don't mutate the state directly.

```
   generateCitiesList = () => {
        const self = this;    
           self.state.cityList.push(citiesList.filter( function (countries) {

                return countries.country === `${self.state.country}`
            }));

        console.log(this.state.cityList);

        this.showCitiesList()  ===> WORKS, pushing desired objects into an array 
        };
```

Populate the state instead in the lifecycle function componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
  const cityList = citiesList.filter(element => element.country === this.state.country);

  this.setState({cityList});
}
```

Comment: I rewrote the code above, you're right. However the syntax in your version doesnt work in my app.

Also, what does this.setState({cityList}) actually mean in this context? I've never seen this kind of syntax. Am I injecting some new cityList object into state somehow?

Comment: `{cityList}` creates an object with a property named `cityList` with the value of the `cityList` variable. It's ES6.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh, so instaed of creating an empty key cityList = [] within state constructor I can create this key on the fly during this.setState state updater?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @Yoav Kadosh (kudos!) I have the answear below.

It turns out that in order to effectively map through a selected number of items you should:

1. Create a function which returns filtered object

Instead, you can also apply chain operators such as variable.filter( (parameter) => parameter > 2).map({element} =>  {element} ).

2. Map over the results of the above function and push them into DOM

```
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
            country: '',
            city: '',
            result: {
               temperature: ''
            }
       }
   }


    handleCountrySelect = (e) => {
           this.setState({
               country: e.target.value
           });
           console.log(e.target.value);

    };


    filterCitiesByCountry = (country) => {
        return citiesJSON.filter ( city => city.country === country)

    };


    handleCitySelect = (e) => {
        this.setState ({
            city: e.target.value
        });

        console.log(e.target.value)

    };


    getWeather = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.state.city},${this.state.country}&appid=${APIKEY}`)
            .then( res => res.json())
            .then( res =>
                this.setState ({
                    result: {
                        temperature: Math.round(res.main.temp - 273.15)
                    }
                })

            )
    };




    render() {

        return (

            <main>

                <section className='row text-center' id='weather_select_section'>
                <form>

                    <div className="countrySelect col-12 col-sm-6 text-center mt-5 mb-5 ">
                        <label> Select Country </label>

                        <select onChange={this.handleCountrySelect} required placeholder='Country...'>

                        <option value='' data-index='Country...'>  </option>

                        { countriesJSON.map(({name, code, key} ) => {
                            return (
                            <option value={code} key={key} > {name} </option>

                            )
                        })}
                    </select>
                    </div>


                    <div className="citySelect col-12 col-sm-6 text-center mt-5 mb-5 ">
                        <label> Select City </label>

                        {this.state.country && (
                            <select onChange={this.handleCitySelect} placeholder='City...' required>
                                <option value='' data-index='City...'></option>


                                { this.filterCitiesByCountry(this.state.country).map(({name, key}) =>
                                    <option value={name} key={key}> {name} </option>

                                )}

                            </select>
                        )

                        }

                    </div>

                    <button type='submit' onClick = {this.getWeather} className=" col-10 mt-5 mb-5 text-center "> Get Weather</button>


                </form>


                <div className=" col-12 WeatherInfoBox ">

                    <h3> Weather in {this.state.city}</h3>
                    <p> {this.state.result.temperature} &#8451;</p>
```